# How can I fix my NodeJS SSE write function to update HTML on subsequent calls?

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

guys I'm experiencing a problem here with SSE (Server-sent Events) from Node.
I'm making a website that receives responses from APIs and delivers them to the user, I manage to receive the first responses that I make changes to the HTML in the client (test0, test1 and test-undefined/undefined) but when I make a request from the client, the one in which the type is 1 or 2, tests in these cases do not appear on the client side.
How can I resolve this?? I started to study the SSE, and I got here, but now I can't go any further.

This is the code:

```
app.get('/ask', async (req, res) => {
  const question = req.query.question;
  const type = req.query.type;
  
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type':'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no=cache',
    'Connection':'keep-alive'
  })
  
  //msg inicial para estabelecer a conexão
  res.write('\n');

  res.write(`data: teste0\n\n`);
  res.flushHeaders();

    res.write(`data: Teste1\n\n`);
    res.flushHeaders();

  try {
    console.log("entrou no /ask");

    if(type==undefined && question==undefined)
    {
      res.write(`data: teste-undefined/undefined\n\n`);
      res.flushHeaders();
      return;
    }

if(type=="type1")
    {
      const data = await executeQuery(type,question);
   
      res.write(`data: Teste2\n\n`);
      res.flushHeaders();
    }

    if(type=="type2")
    {
      console.log('teste3');
      res.write(`data: teste3\n\n`);
      res.flushHeaders();
    }
   
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao interagir com a API', error);
    res.status(500).end('Erro ao interagir com a API');
    console.log(type);
  }
});
```

On the client side I call the SSE like this:

```
<script>
    const eventSource = new EventSource('/ask');
    const resposta_api = document.getElementById('answer');

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      const newElement = document.createElement('p');
      newElement.textContent = `message: ${event.data}`;

      // Atualizar o HTML com a resposta parcial recebida
      resposta_api.appendChild(newElement);
    };
  </script>
```

and my button trigger is this function:

```
<script>
    function askQuestion() {
      const question = document.getElementById('question').value;
      const questionType = document.getElementById('questionType').value;

      let url = `/ask?question=${encodeURIComponent(question)}&type=${encodeURIComponent(questionType)}`;

      // Envia a pergunta para o servidor
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", url, true);
      xhr.send();
    }
  </script>
```

when calling /ask from my button no changes to the HTML is made.
I get no errors from the browser and terminal.
I can see my console.logs of 'teste3' but I don't see the changes on my HTML on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use `/ask/` in two ways, both as an SSE endpoint, and as the place to receive questions.

Once you set up a SSE socket, it is a dedicated one-way connection, data can only flow from server to client. The client cannot write to the socket, the server cannot read from it.

In your code I think you are trying to use SSE as a single-use connection: client asks a question, server sends back the answer, the socket is closed? Using a normal AJAX query is generally simpler.

But if you want to use SSE, e.g. because `await executeQuery()` can be very slow and you are worried about timeouts, then the change you need to make is to not create your EventSource object globally, but to create it in `askQuestion()`. Recreate the object for each question.

Answer (score 1):

That did it Darren Cook, thanks for the help!!

I've merged both of my scripts from the client side to recreate the object for each asked question. and that way I get all my responses as intended!
On the client side I call the SSE like this:

So now my button works like that:

```
<script>
    function askQuestion() {
      const question = document.getElementById('question').value;
      const questionType = document.getElementById('questionType').value;

      let url = `/ask?question=${encodeURIComponent(question)}&type=${encodeURIComponent(questionType)}`;

      // Envia a pergunta para o servidor
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", url, true);
      xhr.send();

 const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
    const resposta_api = document.getElementById('answer');

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      const newElement = document.createElement('p');
      newElement.textContent = `message: ${event.data}`;

      // Atualizar o HTML com a resposta parcial recebida
      resposta_api.appendChild(newElement);
    }
  </script>
```